# Error with Realm when migrating from swift 1.2 to swift 2 (only on Device)

Tags: swift

I need help because I have an error on this line of code since I migrated from swift 1.2 to swift 2 : Here is my code :

```
let toto:Realm=try Realm.init(path: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("initRealm",ofType:"realm")!)
```

And here is the error I get :

Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "open() failed: Operation not permitted" UserInfo={Error Code=1, NSLocalizedDescription=open() failed: Operation not permitted}

I think that the path is ok but looks like the operation is not permited... oddly, it works on simulator but not on my device (iPad)

Any one can help me ?
Thanks a lot.